# $y'=x^3(1-y)$, $y(0) = 3$, why does there have to be a sign change?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation

> $$y'=x^3(1-y), y(0) = 3$$

When I put this in a differential equation solver, it starts off by changing the right hand side to $-x^3(y-1)$ and ends up with the solution $y = e^{(-x^4/4)}+1$. Without this initial step, however, I get a different answer, $y = 1-e^{(x^4/4)}$. Could someone explain why this happens and also why it is necessary to carry out the first step and switch signs before moving on?

Answer (score 2):

The general solution is $$y=ke^{-\frac{x^4}{4}}+1$$

Notice that the solver's solution, your solution, and Moo's solution are all of this form, with different values of $k$.

Next you have to see which value of $k$ gives $y(0) = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Solution should be $$\frac { dy }{ dx } ={ x }^{ 3 }\left( 1-y \right) \\ \int { \frac { dy }{ 1-y } =\int { { x }^{ 3 }dx }  } \\ -\ln { \left| 1-y \right| =\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 4 } +C } \\ 1-y=C{ e }^{ -\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 4 }  }\\ y=1-C{ e }^{ -\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 4 }  }\\ 3=y\left( 0 \right) =1-C\\ C=-2\\$$

> $$ y=1+2{ e }^{ -\frac { { x }^{ 4 } }{ 4 }  }$$

Comment: It should be -2 ,i fixed it thanks @Moo

Comment: Oops, you goofed at the very last step:  $C  = -2$.